# Generic function argument that accepts functions that implement a macro

Tags: python, generics, rust, python-module, pyo3

I'm using pyo3 to add some rust to my python project (for performance), and wanted to create a function to make adding submodules easier. My current code:

```rust
fn register_submodule(name: &str, python: Python, parent: &PyModule, funcs: Vec<?>) -> PyResult<()> {
    let name = &(parent.name()?.to_owned() + name);
    let child = PyModule::new(python, name)?;

    for func in &funcs {
        child.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(func, child)?)?;
    }

    py_run!(python, child, format!("import sys; sys.modules[{}] = child_module", name).as_str());
    parent.add_submodule(child)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I want this function to be able to take an array or vector (or whatever) containing functions that implement the `#[PyFunction]` macro, take any arguments of any type and return a PyResult containing any type, so I can register these to the new module. Is this possible? How would I go about doing it, or achieving a similar result?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it, either no way to pass vector with different functions. Because functions in `Vector` may be very different, may accept different type/count of arguments (how rust will know how to call/use that functions).

The only way to achieve this is with `Enums`.

Create `Enum` with variants of all Python functions eg.

```
enum PyFunctionVariant {
   F1(fn(param1: i32, param2: i32) -> PyResult),
   F2(fn(param1: &str, param2: &str) -> PyResult),
   // all your function definitions
}
```

Change `register_submodule` declaration to accept `Vec` of `PyFunctionVariant`.

```
fn register_submodule(name: &str, python: Python, parent: &PyModule, funcs: Vec<PyFunctionVariant>) -> PyResult<()> {
   ...
}
```

You may also need to change this part with `match`, because now `func` is `Enum` not PyFunction.

```
for func in &funcs {
    child.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(func, child)?)?; // Change Here
}
```

and use this way

```
let functions = vec![
   PyFunctionVariant::F1(add_int),
   PyFunctionVariant::F2(concat_str),
   // etc...
];
register_submodule("module", python, parent, functions)
```

**Edit:** There is also another way, You can use `Vec<Box<dyn Any>>` for passing vector of different functions. [trait Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html)

Comment: could you provide code examples of how you would use those 2 functions inside the `wrap_pyfunction![]` part? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. (i'm new to rust, so sorry if i'm missing something very obvious!)

Comment: I'm not an expert in PyO3 lib, but after some research I found struct `PyFunction` there. I think changing this -> `Vec<?>`  to  `Vec<PyFunction` will fix your problem

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. I will just add the functions from outside the function, thanks for your help.